# Múltiples correos con PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quiero enviar varios email utilizando phpmailer y el problema es que solo envia correo al primer email, ya verifique que el ciclo funcione e investigando un poco al parecer esto solo se puede lograr teniendo los emails en una BD e irlos llamando. Mi pregunta es si se puede lograr como lo estoy haciendo o solo mediante el uso de la BD.
Esta es la pantalla que utilizo para que inserten los email
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código html y la función de javascript para agregar nuevos input

```
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" class="formulario" name="AgregaTriibu" id="AgregaTriibu" >


            </br><label>Escribe los correos de tu Triibu:</label>
            <div class="table-responsive">  <!campos email dinamico>
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field" style="align-items: center;">  
                    <tr>  
                        <td><input type="email" name="correo[]" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control name_list" required/></td>
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success" style="background-color: green; width: 70%; color: white; border: 1px solid green; margin: 0px;"><span class="icon-circle-with-plus"></span></button></td>  
                    </tr>  
                </table>  
            </div>  

            <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="AgregaTriibu.submit();" value="Enviar">

            <?php if(!empty($errores)): ?>
                <div class="error">
                <ul>
                    <?php echo $errores; ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="email" name="correo[]" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control name_list" required/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" style="background-color: red; width: 70%; color: white; border: 1px solid red; margin: 0px;"><span class="icon-circle-with-cross"></span></button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
 });  

</script>
```

Este es el codigo que utilizo para recibir los email y mandar correos

```
    <?php session_start();
require 'Functions.php';//------------------------
ConectarBD();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {//si se enviaron datos por post
    //entonces accedemos a los campos que se enviaron
    $fraccionamiento = $_POST['fraccionamiento'];
    $correos = count($_POST['correo']); //me devuelve el numero inputs que hay, siempre devuelve 1 por esto: Array ( [0] =>)
    //$correo2 = ($_POST['correo']); REGRESA Array ( [0] => laml_1993@hotmail.com [1] => a.mendez93@hotmail.com ) print_r($correo2);

    $errores = '';//variable de errores 
    $fraccionamiento = limpiaNUM($fraccionamiento);


    if (empty($fraccionamiento)) {$errores.= '*Por favor Selecciona un Fraccionamiento <br />'; }
    if ($correos==1 AND $_POST["correo"][0] == '') {    $errores.= '*Por favor ingresa al menos un correo <br />';}//SI HAY 1 EMAIL Y ESTE ESTA VACIO, ENTONCES

    for ($i=0; $i<$correos; $i++) { 
        if(trim($_POST["correo"][$i] != ''))    {//trim quita espacios antes y despues del correo, si post correo es diferente de vacio
        $correoUSER[$i] = filter_var($_POST["correo"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );//LIMPIAMOS CORREO
        if(!filter_var($correoUSER[$i],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ $errores.= '*Por favor ingresa correos válidos <br />';}    }   //TERMINA TRIM    

        if(trim($_POST["correo"][$i] == ''))    {$errores.= '*Por favor rellena todos los campos <br />';}
    }

    if ($errores == '') {
        for($i=0; $i<$correos; $i++){  
            //VERIFICO SI LOS CORREOS ESTAN EN LA BD
            $statement = $conexion-> prepare('SELECT * FROM iniciosesion WHERE E_Mail_ini_ses = :email LIMIT 1');
            $statement->execute(array(':email' => $correoUSER[$i]));
            $resultado = $statement->fetch();//regresa false si el correo no esta en la BD(true o false)


            if ($resultado == false) {//si el correo no esta en la BD entonces

                /*PONGO DATOS PARA CREAR CUENTA NUEVA Y LA INSERTO EN LA BD*/

                //MANDAMOS CORREO PARA ACTIVACIÓN DE CUENTA
                $asunto = 'Activar Cuenta Tribu';
                $cuerpo = "msj";

                enviarEmail($correoUSER[$i], $asunto, $cuerpo);

                } else {// SI EL CORREO ESTA EN LA BD

                    //MANDAMOS CORREO PARA avisar que el admin lo dio de alta

                    $asunto2 = 'Tu Administrador te ha agregado';
                    $cuerpo2 = "MSJ.";

                    enviarEmail($correoUSER[$i], $asunto2, $cuerpo2) ;

                }//termina else de si esta en la BD

        }//TERMINA CICLO FOR
    }//TERMINA IF ERRORES
}//TERMINA POST
}
```

Y esta es la funcion de enviar email

```
function enviarEmail($email, $asunto, $cuerpo){
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
    $mail->SMTPSecure ='tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port ='587';
    $mail->Username = 'correo@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'pass';

    $mail->setFrom('correo@gmail.com', 'Sistema de Usuarios');
    $mail->addAddress($email,'Estimado Usuario'); 

    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body = $cuerpo;
    $mail->ISHTML(true);

    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    ));

    if ($mail->send()) {
        return true;
        //echo "enviado";
    } else{
        return false;
        //echo "error";
    }   

    $mail->clearAddresses();//limpiamos addresses para el siguiente ciclo
    $mail->clearAttachments();

}
```

Comment: Nos falta el código html del formulario en dónde están los campos de correo para saber como los envías. En general, cada campo del form tiene un nombre, por ejemplo, correo1, correo2, entonces, en el PHP, debes recoger $_POST["correo1"], $_POST["correo2"], etc... y luego tienes que hacer el bucle en base a dichos correos. El resto está bien.

Comment: ya puse el codigo html, el detalle es que no puedo definir un número finito de inputs y los agrego mediante un botón y una función de javascript, de tal forma que el usuario puede ingresar el número que quiera

Comment: Prueba a hacer un debug del $_POST["correo"], tal vez no es un array y es un objeto, entonces el bucle sería algo así como foreach($_POST['correo'] as $c){}. Mira esta solución si no funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148743/php-post-get-data-array

Comment: Si hago un print_r($_POST['correo']); me regresa Array ( [0] => correo@hotmail.com [1] => correo2@hotmail.com )

Comment: y ya cheque que si funciona el ciclo, me inserta todos los correos que se reciben por post a la BD  y checa si ya estaban en la BD pero solo envia el correo al primer correo que se inserto a los demás no les hace caso. Anduve leyendo y al parecer no es posible así porque se genera un cuello de botella ya que tarda mucho al enviar el correo y no espera a que termine esa funcion, entonces lo que hacen es subir los correos a una BD y de ahi los van llamando para enviar el correo, pero no veo la diferencia entre tenerlos en un array y tenerlos en la BD. En inglés se conoce como Bulk email.

Comment: No sé si lo que comentas será cierto o no, pero en mi caso, he usado PHPMailer y siempre he podido enviar más de un correo sin problemas.

Comment: tendras algun ejemplo donde envies varios correos al mismo tiempo? para ver en donde me estoy equivocando, sería de gran ayuda track3r

Comment: Mejor, te paso un enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149452/php-mailer-multiple-address mis ejemplos son similares al tuyo.

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré.

Comment: Disculpen la tardanza, me funcionó perfecto el foreach gracias track3r